# Swift: Read/grab Barcode from Still image/UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, barcode

Is there a way I can grab a barcode on an UIImage in Swift?

There's a lot of info about AVFoundation, that recognizes barcodes from the Camera input. AVFoundation recognizes lots of barcodes and seems perfect, but I can't figure out how to 'read' an UIImage instead of the Camera input. I've tried CIDetector, but barcode recognization with 'CIDetectorTypeRectangle' is limited and also grabs other rectangle types.

If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: check for `RedLasser` api.

Comment: Shut down per 2016 :(

Comment: Hmm, thinking that I should continue with CIDetector and change the CIDetectorAspectRatio to try and find the different barcodes.

Comment: @TomWolters I also want to do same things, have you get the answer?